# Why is it duplicating answers when inserting them into database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am inserting values into a "Question" and "Answer" Table. Now the Question Table is fine as that if I insert 2 questions then the table it displays is below:

```
SessionId (PK)  QuestionId(Pk) QuestionContent  

RZC             1              Name 2 things you will find with a computer
RZC             2              Name three things you will find in a toolbox
```

But the "Answer" Table is causing the problem, it duplicates the answers when it inserts, the table currently looks like below:

```
AnswerId (auto PK)   SessionId  QuestionId  Answer
1                    RZC         1          A
2                    RZC         1          C
3                    RZC         2          A
4                    RZC         2          B
5                    RZC         2          E
6                    RZC         1          A
7                    RZC         1          C
8                    RZC         2          A
9                    RZC         2          B
10                   RZC         2          E
```

The table should look like below:

```
AnswerId (auto PK)   SessionId  QuestionId  Answer
1                    RZC         1          A
2                    RZC         1          C
3                    RZC         2          A
4                    RZC         2          B
5                    RZC         2          E
```

Why is it duplicating answers?

Below is the php and mysqli code:

```
   <?php

    var_dump($_POST);  


    // Prepare your statements ahead of time
    $questionsql = 'INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
        // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
    }

    $answersql = 'INSERT INTO Answer (SessionId, QuestionId, Answer) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
        // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
    }


        //make sure both prepared statements succeeded before proceeding
            if( $insert && $insertanswer)
            {
                $sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');
                $c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);

                for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ )
                {

$insert->bind_param('sis', $sessid, $_POST['numQuestion'][$i], $_POST['questionText'][$i]);

       $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) 
        {
        // Handle query error here
        echo __LINE__.': '.$insert->error;
        break 2;
        }   


        $results = $_POST['value'];
        foreach($results as $id => $value) 
        {
        $answer = $value;

        $lastID = $insert->insert_id;



        foreach($value as $answer) 
        {
        $insertanswer->bind_param('sis', $sessid, $lastID, $answer);

        $insertanswer->execute();

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
        // Handle query error here
        echo __LINE__.': '.$insertanswer->error;
        break 3;
        }
        }
        }
        }

                //close your statements at the end
                $insertanswer->close();
                $insert->close();
            } 
            ?>
```

The var_dump($_POST) shows this below:

```
array(4) {
    ["numQuestion"]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(1) "1"
        [1]=> string(1) "2"
    }
    ["questionText"]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(20) "What is 2+2 and 3+3?"
        [1]=> string(41) "Which three items will you find in a car?"
    }
    ["submitDetails"]=> string(14) "Submit Details" 
    ["value"]=> array(2) {
        [1]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(1) "A"
            [1]=> string(1) "C"
        }
        [2]=> array(3) {
            [0]=> string(1) "A"
            [1]=> string(1) "B"
            [2]=> string(1) "D"
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you visit the page twice?

Comment: What's `$insert` and `$insertanswer`?

Comment: @Jeffrey Oops forgot to copy the insert statements in code, give me 30 secs.

Comment: @lc. No I did not visit page twice

Comment: Code updated showing what $insert and $insertanswer is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a loop nesting problem. The for, if I get it right, is running the questions and the foreach the answers. The problem is that they should be indipendent from each other. In your code, instead, the foreach is run at every question causing the answers to be inserted twice.

This should work:

```
<?php

    var_dump($_POST);  

    // Prepare your statements ahead of time
    $questionsql = 'INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
        // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
    }

    $answersql = 'INSERT INTO Answer (SessionId, QuestionId, Answer) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
        // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
    }

    //make sure both prepared statements succeeded before proceeding
    if($insert && $insertanswer) {
        $sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');
        $c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);
        for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ) {
            $insert->bind_param('sis', $sessid, $_POST['numQuestion'][$i], $_POST['questionText'][$i]);
            $insert->execute();
            if ($insert->errno) {
                // Handle query error here
                echo __LINE__.': '.$insert->error;
                break 2;
            }   
        }

        $results = $_POST['value'];
        foreach($results as $id => $value) {
            $answer = $value;
            $lastID = $insert->insert_id;

            foreach($value as $answer) {
                $insertanswer->bind_param('sis', $sessid, $lastID, $answer);
                $insertanswer->execute();

                if ($insertanswer->errno) {
                    // Handle query error here
                    echo __LINE__.': '.$insertanswer->error;
                    break 3;
                }
            }
        }

        //close your statements at the end
        $insertanswer->close();
        $insert->close();
    } 

?>
```

Comment: So I need to move the closing bracket for the for loop before answers (before foreach loop)?

Comment: You need to insert the questions, close all the question loops and **then** start the loops for the answers.

Comment: Cool cheers Jeffrey :) Can I ask one little question, should $lastID be moved from foreach loop and moved into for loop? This inserts QuestionId for each answer in "Answer" Table but problem is that it keeps displaying "0" for QuestionId in Answer Table now

Comment: @user1701484, I'm sorry but in this line: `$lastID = $insert->insert_id;`, `$insert` has type `PDOStatement` which has no `insert_id` property by default as described here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php.

Comment: Oh haha, didn't know that, but what is strange is that this line of code did work before I seperated the foreach loop and for loop, this line of code also worked for another php page I have where it inserts values. strange, should the $lastID variable need to be placed somewhere else in the php/mysqli code?

Comment: Ok if you look at the Question and Answer Table in my question, A question obviously has answers. What the $lastID variable does is that it by retrieving the last Question number inserted in the "Question" Table, it determines which answer belongs to that Question number (QuestionId), does that make sense? Btw this link(http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) states that what I used `$lastID = $insert->insert_id;` is mysqli but object oriented style

Comment: Try replacing that line with `$lastID = $id;`.